# Searching in ElasticSearch using Get Request

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I am trying to search for documents in ElasticSearch .
I want to pass the query string as JSON . I am unable to do that.
How can I do that?

I  want to pass this JSON request body in my search request.

```
{"query": { 
    "bool": { 
      "must": [
        { "match": { "last_name":   "Doe"   }}
    ]
  }
}}
```

Comment: How are you making the request? What happens when you make it? An exception? No data? Something else? If you don't provide these details then you won't get a relevant answer.

Comment: I want to send request through url containing json request body for my query

Answer (score 0):

In order to send a request, you would need to define the header as `application/json` and send a POST/GET request to _search endpoint. Below is a sample CURL request for reference which can be run in the terminal.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"query": {"bool": { "must": [{ "match": { "last_name":"Doe"   }}]}}}' "http://localhost:9200/index_name/_search"
```

Link for reference: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html
Hope it helps.